# oracle 9i client connecting to oracle 12c server

Tags: oracle12c, oracleclient

Can Oracle 9.2 client connect to Oracle 12c server?
We have an old server which is an 11g version, and so far there's no problem connecting from client.

Thank You.

Answer (score 2):

That isn't a supported combination, no. As it says [in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NTCLI/overview.htm#NTCLI1236), you can see the supported client/server combinations at [My Oracle Support](https://support.oracle.com) note 207303.1.

The 9i client used to be supported with an 11g server, but is not with a 12c server. There is a specific note about it:

> Attempting to connect from 9.2 to 12.1 will fail with an "ORA-28040: No matching authentication protocol" error.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But the ORA-28040 can be fixed by adding SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION_CLIENT from this document. https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NETRF/sqlnet.htm#NETRF2010

Comment: @njihan - it still isn't a supported combination though. Even if you get it to connect, there may be things that don't work quite right.  Or you may get lucky, but I wouldn't run anything important unsupported.

Comment: Noted that. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

We are currently using the 9i 32bit Client to connect to Oracle 12c 64bit server in test at the moment and so far it works but with caution.

For example, whenever you query certain data types not available in 9i but available in 12c, the system may crash. We therefore had to build views that convert the timestamp data type to the date data type for example. Then it works fine. Even use of indexes seem to work fine.

Comment: I have same issue here oracle 9i to oracle 12c do you face any issues till now? please update your answer thanks